# Генератор псевдослучайного числа в бинарном представлении

Tags: случайные-числа, системы-счисления, julia

Возникла необходимость генерировать псевдослучайное число в бинарном представлении (из трех октетов), например, `10101111 00011100 00100001` или `00111100 01111000 01101101` (так как в конечном итоге результат будет представлен типом string, пробелы необязательны). Полагаю это как-то реализовывается через метод `rand`, но это только предположение. Я так и не смогла найти в официальной документации нужного направления в решении задачи. Прошу указать мне верное направление.

Comment: Ну так сгенерируйте, скажем, 3 псевдослучайных от 0 до 255 и переведите в двоичную систему. Вот Вам 4 числа в бинарном представлении из 8 цифр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно наиболее простым в данном случае будет такое решение:

```
s = join(rand(0:1, 24))
```

Сперва получаем двадцать четыре числа в диапазоне от нуля до единицы, после чего `join` формирует из этих чисел строку вида `101010101100000111111100`, - эдакое псевдослучайное бинарное число. Если все же нужно поделить строку на октеты:

```
join([s[i:i+7] for i in 1:8:24], " ")
```

Здесь в цикле извлекаются подстроки длиной восемь символов каждая, после чего подстроки объединяются в строку (через пробел), - напомню, что индекс первого элемента массива в *Julia* равен *1*. В принципе, можно использовать регулярные выражения для деления строки, но это уже дело вкуса.